# some problems in html and css codes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code a Calculator interface 
I'm facing two problems :
1) why these buttons' (.,+) dimensions are not accurate 
2) why this code :

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(81, 122, 121);
  border: 7px solid rgb(213, 236, 213);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 45px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.button20 {
  background-color: rgb(36, 117, 117);
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 285px;
  height: 45px;
}

.button19 {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.style {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="button button20">0</div>
<div>
  <button class="button">7</button>
  <button class="button">8</button>
  <button class="button">9</button>

</div>

<div>
  <button class="button">4</button>
  <button class="button">5</button>
  <button class="button">6</button>

</div>
<div>
  <button class="button">1</button>
  <button class="button">2</button>
  <button class="button">3</button>

</div>
<div>
  <button class="button">0</button>
  <button class="button button12">.</button>
  <button class="button">±</button>

</div>
<div>
  <button class="button button14">×</button>
  <button class="button">+</button>
  <button class="button button16">-</button>

</div>
<div>
  <button class="button">÷</button>
  <button class="button">=</button>
  <button class=" button button19">Clear</button>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: CSS codes:
.button {
    background-color: rgb(81, 122, 121);
    border: 7px solid rgb(213, 236, 213);
    color : white;
    padding: 10px 45px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.button20 {
    background-color: rgb(36, 117, 117);
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 285px;
    height: 45px;
}

.button19 {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.style {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculator interface.css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Calculater interface</title>
```

.button,
        .result {
            background-color: rgb(81, 122, 121);
            border: 6px solid rgb(213, 236, 213);
            color: white;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

```
    .result {
        background-color: rgb(36, 117, 117);
        width: 286px;
    }

    .button {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
    }
</style>



<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="result">0</div>

    <div>

        <button class="button">7</button>

        <button class="button">8</button>

        <button class="button">9</button>

    </div>



    <div>

        <button class="button">4</button>

        <button class="button">5</button>

        <button class="button">6</button>

    </div>

    <div>

        <button class="button">1</button>

        <button class="button">2</button>

        <button class="button">3</button>

    </div>

    <div>

        <button class="button">0</button>

        <button class="button">.</button>

        <button class="button">±</button>

    </div>

    <div>

        <button class="button">×</button>

        <button class="button">+</button>

        <button class="button">-</button>

    </div>

    <div>

        <button class="button">÷</button>

        <button class="button">=</button>

        <button class=" button">Clear</button>

    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the whole thing in a div with `display: flex;` and removing all the other divs.

Then add extra styling for `.button20` so it takes up the whole row.

```css
.calculator {
  width: 285px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(81, 122, 121);
  border: 7px solid rgb(213, 236, 213);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  flex: 1 0 33.3%;
}

.button20 {
  background-color: rgb(36, 117, 117);
  text-align: right;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <button class="button20">0</button>

  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>

  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>

  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>

  <button>0</button>
  <button>.</button>
  <button>±</button>

  <button>×</button>
  <button>+</button>
  <button>-</button>

  <button>÷</button>
  <button>=</button>
  <button>Clear</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by changing your CSS. I have edited your code. 
This is work as you expect.

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(81, 122, 121);
  border: 7px solid rgb(213, 236, 213);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 45px;
  font-size: 25px;
width: 117px !important;
}

.button20 {
  background-color: rgb(36, 117, 117);
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 281px !important;
  height: 45px;
}

.button19 {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.style {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="button button20">0</div>
<div>
  <button class="button">7</button>
  <button class="button">8</button>
  <button class="button">9</button>

</div>

<div>
  <button class="button">4</button>
  <button class="button">5</button>
  <button class="button">6</button>

</div>
<div>
  <button class="button">1</button>
  <button class="button">2</button>
  <button class="button">3</button>

</div>
<div>
  <button class="button">0</button>
  <button class="button button12">.</button>
  <button class="button">±</button>

</div>
<div>
  <button class="button button14">×</button>
  <button class="button">+</button>
  <button class="button button16">-</button>

</div>
<div>
  <button class="button">÷</button>
  <button class="button">=</button>
  <button class=" button button19">Clear</button>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's fine now
Thank you so much